# Align 3 rectangle horizontally

Tags: html, alignment, css-position

I have 3 rectangles that I want to align all horizontally and evenly space out from the middle, I try to use position: flex and white-space: nowrap but none of them work and I'm not sure why it doesn't work, the rectangle only appear vertically.

HTML code:

```
<div class="plots">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.plots {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: flex;
}

.plots > div{
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 35vh;
    width: 14vw;
    margin-top: 2.1vh;
    border-radius: 10%;
}
```

What I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/scpPu.png

Comment: Instead of `position: flex;` try `display: flex;`

Comment: use `display: flex;` and `justify-content:space-around` or `space-between`

Answer (score 1):

use display:flex; property

```css
.plots {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
}
```